# How to read csv without header and name them with names while reading in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

```
100000,20160214,93374987
100000,20160214,1925301
100000,20160216,1896542
100000,20160216,84167419
100000,20160216,77273616
100000,20160507,1303015
```

I want to read the csv file which has no column names in first row.
How to read it and name the columns with my specified names in the same time ?
for now, I just renamed the original columns with my specified names like this:

```
df = spark.read.csv("user_click_seq.csv",header=False)
df = df.withColumnRenamed("_c0", "member_srl")
df = df.withColumnRenamed("_c1", "click_day")
df = df.withColumnRenamed("_c2", "productid")
```

Any better way ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can import the csv file into a dataframe with a predefined schema. The way you define a schema is by using the `StructType` and `StructField` objects. Assuming your data is all `IntegerType` data:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("member_srl", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("click_day", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("productid", IntegerType(), True)])

df = spark.read.csv("user_click_seq.csv",header=False,schema=schema)
```

should work.

Comment: thanks. if the column is string type, then I will replace the IntegerType() with StringType(), is that right ?

Comment: Yes, just make sure to import `StringType` from `pyspark.sql.types`

Comment: this solution didn't work for me. The columns of the dataframe were '_c0', '_c1' even when I used the schema argument as mentioned. I had to follow the workaround mentioned in the question, i.e. to use withColumnRenamed() to rename the column names.

Answer (score 32):

For those who would like to do this in scala and may not want to add types:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
                   .option("header","false")
                   .load("hdfs_filepath")
                   .toDF("var0","var1","var2","var3")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can read the data with `header=False` and then pass the column names with `toDF` as below:

```
data = spark.read.csv('data.csv', header=False)
data = data.toDF('name1', 'name2', 'name3')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it handled many columns and creating a schema was very tedious when, in addition, spark inferred the schema well.
So I opted to rename it using a select.

First I create a list with the new names:

```
val listNameColumns: List[String] = List("name1", "name2" , "name3")
```

Then I combine the column names of the original dataframe with the above list and create a list of Column elements:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val selectStament: Array[Column] = df.columns zip listNameColumns map { case(a, b) =>  col(a).as(b)}
```

Finally I make the select:

```
val dfRenamed = df.select(selectStament:_*)
```