# Spark scala create dataframe from text with columns split by delimiter |

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to create a spark dataframe from text file in which data is delimited by | symbol.
Have to Spark with Scala.
The text files has data as below:

```
John|1234|$2500|giggle
Ross|1344|$5500|Micsoft
Jennifer|5432|$2100|healthcare
```

```
val schemaString = "name,employeeid,salary,company"
val fields = schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName,StringType, nullable=true))
val schema = StructType(fields)
val rddView= sc.textFile("/dev/path/*").map(_.split("|")).map{x
    => org.apache.spark.sql.Row(x:_*)}
    val rddViewDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddView,schema)

rddViewDf.show()
```

Expecting the values to be mapped to corresponding columns but output is not as expected.
Can someone provide the correct solution in Spark using scala language

Output I am getting:

```
+----+----------+------+-------+
|name|employeeid|salary|company|
+----+----------+------+-------+
|   J|         o|     h|      n|
|   R|         o|     s|      s|
|   J|         e|     n|      n|
+----+----------+------+-------+
```

Expected Output

```
+----------+------------+----------+-----------+
|name      |employeeid  |    salary|    company|
+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+
|     John|         1234|     $2500|     giggle|
|     Ross|         1344|     $5500|    Micsoft|
| Jennifer|         5432|     $2100| healthcare|
+----+----------+------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Please update your Question to include what output you are currently getting, and how it does not match what you are expecting. Please also include what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Updated the question with output I am getting and expected output

Comment: Tried escape character with | symbol and it worked. split("\\|")

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your split delimeter is incorrect.

However, you should not be using RDDs anyway

```
scala> spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("data.txt").show()
+--------+----+-----+----------+
|     _c0| _c1|  _c2|       _c3|
+--------+----+-----+----------+
|    John|1234|$2500|    giggle|
|    Ross|1344|$5500|   Micsoft|
|Jennifer|5432|$2100|healthcare|
+--------+----+-----+----------+
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html

To rename the columns, please see this and translate to Scala [How to read csv without header and name them with names while reading in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558139/how-to-read-csv-without-header-and-name-them-with-names-while-reading-in-pyspark)

Note: Ideally, your employeeId column is defined as a LongType, not StringType