# How to convert header of csv into valid data of pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, validation, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

I am reading the csv data with Defined Schema. Whereas in that valid data from header is getting overwrited with schema.

I want header to get in 1st row of dataframe.

Comment: It seems you want to read a csv file that has no header. You can do this by setting the `option("header", "false")` while reading the csv. (e.g., `spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("my_path")` )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read csv without header and name them with names while reading in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558139/how-to-read-csv-without-header-and-name-them-with-names-while-reading-in-pyspark)